# Vector of Vectors of CStrings initialization and usage

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings, libharu

I am trying to create a Vector of Vectors of CStrings; a two dimensional array of CStrings. This will represent the data in a table. (All data is a CString of course).

Here is how I try to initialize the Vector>

```
std::vector<std::vector<CString>> tableData;
    for(int r = 0; r < oTA.rows; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < oTA.cols; c++)
            tableData[r][c] = "Test";
```

And here is how I try to use it

```
for(int r = 0; r < tabAtt.rows; r++)
    {
        // TextYpos = bottom of table + 5(padding) + (row height * row we're on)
        HPDF_REAL textYpos = tabAtt.tabY + 5 + (r*tabAtt.rowH);
        for(int c = 0; c < tabAtt.cols; c++)
        {
            // TextXpos = left of table + 5(padding) + (col width * col we're on)
            HPDF_REAL textXpos = tabAtt.tabX + 5 + c*tabAtt.colW;
            HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, textXpos, textYpos, (CT2A)tableData[r][c]); // HERE!
        }
    }
```

But I think that I am not initializing it properly. I keep getting a vector out of bounds error.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you need to allocate the memory and construct your vector elements prior to accessing them. This should work:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CString>> tableData;
for(int r = 0; r < oTA.rows; r++)
{
    tableData.push_back(std::vector<CString>());
    for(int c = 0; c < oTA.cols; c++)
       tableData.back().push_back("Test");
}
```

or, slightly more efficient:

```
std::vector<std::vector<CString>> tableData(oTA.rows,std::vector<CString>(oTA.cols));
for(int r = 0; r < oTA.rows; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < oTA.cols; c++)
       tableData[r][c]="Test";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize `std::vector` entries with indexed access via `[]` if you haven't already pushed anything into the vector or initialized it with a size and fill ([see `vector`'s constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)).  So this will cause problems when `tableData` is empty and `oTA.rows` or `oTA.cols` are `0`.

```
for(int r = 0; r < oTA.rows; r++)
    for(int c = 0; c < oTA.cols; c++)
        tableData[r][c] = "Test";
```

You should use `vector::push_back()` to add the data:

```
for(int r = 0; r < oTA.rows; r++) {
    tableData.push_back(std::vector<CString>());
    for(int c = 0; c < oTA.cols; c++) {
        tableData.back().push_back("Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simple access a std::vector without adding items first. Either use std::vector::push_back() or use a constructor [Cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector///)